# ¿Como puedo usar un método que recibe un parametro de tipo context en un clase fragment y poder usarlo a en la clase producto una clase normal

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación en android studio.

Tengo una clase fragments_producto y tengo un metodo donde obtengo la ip automáticamente ese si me funciona, el detalle es mandarlo a llamar dentro de otra clase :

```
   protected String wifiIpAddress(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
    context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();

    // Convert little-endian to big-endianif needed
    if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)) {
        ipAddress = Integer.reverseBytes(ipAddress);
    }

    byte[] ipByteArray = BigInteger.valueOf(ipAddress).toByteArray();

    try {
        ipAddressString = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipByteArray).getHostAddress();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mi ip: " + ipAddressString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Log.e("WIFIIP", "Unable to get host address.");
        ipAddressString = null;
    }
    return ipAddressString;

}
```

---

mi otra clase llamado productos es una clase java normal

```
       public class productos implements Parcelable {

       public static ArrayList<productos> lista() {

        try {
            final ArrayList<productos> productos = new ArrayList<productos>();
            Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.127.189/android/consulta.php");
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        con.connect();
                        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
                        String respuesta = "", linea = "";
                        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            respuesta += linea + "\n";
                        }
                        System.out.println("respuesta=" + respuesta);
                        JSONArray arreglo = new JSONArray(respuesta);
                        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject objeto = arreglo.getJSONObject(i);
                            productos p = new productos();
                            p.nombre = objeto.getString("nombre_producto");

                            productos.add(p);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            hilo.start();
            while (hilo.isAlive()) {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            return productos;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

---

y quiero mandar a llamar el metodo wifiAddress en la clase productos, que la ip que obtengo automaticamente reemplazarlo con la ip que esta fijo.

este trozo de codigo he intentado solucionar, mandando a llamar el metodo wifiAddress en la clase producto, pero me sigue marcando error.

```
   Context context;
    final Productos_Fragment productosFragment = new Productos_Fragment();
    productosFragment.wifiIpAddress(context);
```

me da este error:

```
    vaiable 'context' might not have been initialized
```

me podrian explicar cual es mi error!!!

!!!!  gracias   !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Obtienes el error:

> variable 'context' might not have been initialized

porque precisamente la variable `context` no tiene valor ya que no la has inicializado, si te encuentras en una `Activity` puedes inicializar el valor usando `getApplicationContext()`.

```
//inicializa contexto.
Context context = getApplicationContext();

final Productos_Fragment productosFragment = new Productos_Fragment();
productosFragment.wifiIpAddress(context);
```